# How do I use a case statement to assign a value from another row?

Tags: mysql, case, variable-assignment

I have a table with IDs that are NOT distinct.  There is a date field, and a field title RISK with values such as 'None', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High'.  It looks like this:

```
    ID  Date    Risk
    1743333 12/1/2017   Low
    1743333 12/2/2017   Low
    1743333 12/3/2017   None
    1743333 12/4/2017   None
    1743333 12/5/2017   Medium
    1743333 12/6/2017   High
    1265464 12/1/2017   High
    1265464 12/2/2017   None
    1265464 12/3/2017   None
    1265464 12/4/2017   None
    1265464 12/5/2017   High
    1265464 12/6/2017   High
```

The RISK field is built by other data points and calculations in code I don't have or know exactly what the criteria for it is. The 'None' value is essentially assigned when there is not enough info to assign Low,Med or High based on the calculation criteria.  What I am trying to do is, where the values in RISK ='None', I would like to assign the previous row's RISK value based on the previous date (1day earlier) within that particular ID.  So, on any given day, if RISK is anything besides 'None' and then becomes 'None' as the days progress, I want to maintain the previous latest non 'None' value. The new table would end up looking like this:

```
ID  Date    Risk
1743333 12/1/2017   Low
1743333 12/2/2017   Low
1743333 12/3/2017   Low
1743333 12/4/2017   Low
1743333 12/5/2017   Medium
1743333 12/6/2017   High
1265464 12/1/2017   High
1265464 12/2/2017   High
1265464 12/3/2017   High
1265464 12/4/2017   High
1265464 12/5/2017   Medium
1265464 12/6/2017   High
```

I am not familiar with it it, but I was thinking about iterating through the rows with variable assignments. I am using MySQL and am trying to implement this into a case statement so I can assigned the result to a new field in my existing table.  Been running into issue with referencing or joining back to the same table in MySQL. Thanks in advance and sorry for the lengthy post!

Comment: Show us some code.  We are here to help you fix bad code, not make you code

Comment: `case expressions` only work on the current row, not across rows (nb they are not "case statements")

Answer (score 0):

A self-join using a date difference can be achieved as follows. However you will note that 'none' will still occurs in the result.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e904/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`ID` int, `Date` datetime, `Risk` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`ID`, `Date`, `Risk`)
VALUES
    (1743333, '2017-12-01 00:00:00', 'Low'),
    (1743333, '2017-12-02 00:00:00', 'Low'),
    (1743333, '2017-12-03 00:00:00', 'None'),
    (1743333, '2017-12-04 00:00:00', 'None'),
    (1743333, '2017-12-05 00:00:00', 'Medium'),
    (1743333, '2017-12-06 00:00:00', 'High'),
    (1265464, '2017-12-01 00:00:00', 'High'),
    (1265464, '2017-12-02 00:00:00', 'None'),
    (1265464, '2017-12-03 00:00:00', 'None'),
    (1265464, '2017-12-04 00:00:00', 'None'),
    (1265464, '2017-12-05 00:00:00', 'High'),
    (1265464, '2017-12-06 00:00:00', 'High')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
       t.*, prev.risk as prev_risk
from table1 as t
inner join table1 as prev on t.id = prev.id and t.date = prev.date + interval 1 day
where t.risk = 'none'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e904/4/0)**:

```
|      ID |                 Date | Risk | prev_risk |
|---------|----------------------|------|-----------|
| 1743333 | 2017-12-03T00:00:00Z | None |       Low |
| 1743333 | 2017-12-04T00:00:00Z | None |      None |
| 1265464 | 2017-12-02T00:00:00Z | None |      High |
| 1265464 | 2017-12-03T00:00:00Z | None |      None |
| 1265464 | 2017-12-04T00:00:00Z | None |      None |
```